# Navigation to child routes gives error "cannot match any routes"

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my routes,Created child components and I can see the default child route in the router outlet.But when navigate to the other child routes ,shows error  "cannot match any routes".

**routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent
},
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: DashboardhomeComponent
      } ,
       {
        path: 'profile',
         pathMatch: 'full',
        component: ProfileComponent
      } 
    ] 
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },

];
```

**dashboard.ts**

```
goto() {
  this.router.navigate(['dashboard/profile']);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/profile']);
```

and change your route as,

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboardhome',
    component: DashboardhomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }           

    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },

];
```

Comment: shows "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/profile'" the same error.

Comment: @Sajeetharam U can see the complete code here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E2jtFuU_dU6102v-r2ePZ8fesciTKpCV

Comment: @Sajeetharan the route change you suggested might end up in and infinite loop call to the route “dashboard” and he won’t be able to go to “DashboardHomeComponent”